# AlarmManager alarm fires immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm testing `AlarmManager` to use in my app, and it is firing my Broadcast Receiver immediately when I want it to fire after 1 minute. The code is below:

```
public class SetMealTimersActivity extends Activity {
    PendingIntent pi;
    BroadcastReceiver br;
    AlarmManager am;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_meal_timers);

        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Ready to Go!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("com.ian.mealtimer"));
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                "com.ian.mealtimer"), 0);
        am = (AlarmManager) (this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));         
        am.set( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 
                60 * 1000, pi );
    }
```

Comment: `Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            //set the alarm for particular time
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)); where time = 60*1000`

Answer (score 4):

try :

```
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
      Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

it is working for me.

Comment: I just substituted your code for the last line in my code but it is still not working for me - the Broadcast Receiver is firing immediately ???

Answer (score 2):

If using an exact alarm, make sure it's time is in the future. Otherwise it will fire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` to `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` to `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`.

Comment: That gives me "The method currentTimeInMillis() is undefined for the type System"

Comment: Sorry, it's currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Typo - System.currentTimeMillis() was accepted. Still get the same problem though - the Broadcast Receiver fires immediately, rather than 1 minute later

Comment: Change ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP to RTC or RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: Tried that too (both RTC and RTC_WAKEUP). No difference - still fires immediately????

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `AlarmManager.setExact(int, long, PendingIntent)` if you use Android API > 18 or compile with API < 19, because the time management for this methods changed with API 19. Maybe that helps.  Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for more information.

Comment: setExact (using the same parameters as before) gives exactly the same result - immediate firing of the broadcast receiver :0(

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? Is the BroadcastReceiver really called after AlarmManager.set ? Or is it called immediately after registration of the receiver?

Comment: Apologies - my BroadcastReceiver was not actually being called, it was simply that the Activity in which it was defined was being displayed. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

make `id` for `pendingIntent` as this

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 999123266,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

All example

```
public void setAlarm_sat(int dayOfWeek1) {
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RemmemberActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 999123266,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Long alarmTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    alarmTime,7*24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
                    pendingIntent);
    // am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, cal1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```